# How to Hydrate a poco from his ToString

Tags: c#, serialization

I often create Poco that only have a few primitive properties.
I am used to use Resharper for overriding the ToString.
Resharper ToString result looks like : "Prop1:Val1,Prop2:Val2,...,Propn:Valn"

When the application missbehave, I always see the ToString of this Poco in the logs.
I would like to create a method that hydrate this Poco from his serialised value.
With that, I can quickly unit test potential bugs replaying logs.

I would like to implement a Method with this signature :

```
public void HydrateFromToString(string serialised){/*...*/}
```

I am currently trying a solution, I will quickly post it when it is ready.

Comment: `ToString` is not guaranteed to (and does not by default) produce a serialized representation of an object. If you *have* a serialized representation of an object, then all you need is an appropriate deserializer.

Comment: The all point is that I am using resharper that always produce the ToString with this format.

Comment: You should use JSON (NewtonsSoft) to write your logs. deserialization comes for free with it.

Comment: I feel you are right, I am reimplementing a bad version of Json

Comment: Yep totally agree - use JSON from NewtonSoft. Then the ToString () becomes just `return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this);` and it gives you a string you can deserialise using `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YourType>(serialised);`

Answer (score 0):

Please consider first following Matthew advice :

> Use JSON from NewtonSoft. Then the ToString () becomes just return  JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this); and it gives you a string you can deserialise using JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(serialised);

***AVOID USING THIS***

This is my workso far, it is a good base for most of my Poco.

```
    public void HydrateFromToString(string serialised)
    {
        var currentType = GetType();
        foreach (var keyValuePair in serialised.Split(new[]{','}))
        {
            var trimmedKeyValuePair = keyValuePair.Trim();
            var splitted = trimmedKeyValuePair.Split(new[] {':'}, 2);
            if(splitted.Length != 2)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("There is no comma to separate this keyValuePair : "+trimmedKeyValuePair);
            }
            var propertyName = splitted[0].Trim();
            var value = splitted[1].Trim();
            var propInfo = currentType.GetProperty(propertyName);
            try
            {
                if (propInfo.GetSetMethod() != null)
                {
                    var propertyType = propInfo.PropertyType;

                    if (propertyType.IsEnum)
                    {
                        if (!Enum.IsDefined(propertyType, value))
                                throw new ArgumentException("Enum value not handled!");
                        propInfo.SetValue(this,  Enum.Parse(propertyType, value), null);
                        continue;
                    }
                    propInfo.SetValue(this, Convert.ChangeType(value, propertyType), null);
                }                }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                   //Log, alert do something!
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do not reinvent the wheel